# Selecting a file from a stated directory in Python

Tags: python, file, select, directory-listing

I want to select a file by numbers at left side of listing but I can't go more than this:

```
import os
path="/root/Desktop"
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
    print fname

selected = raw_input("Select a file above: ")
```

What should I do?

Example:

http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/4407/listingy.png

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following :

```
import os
path="/root/Desktop"
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for i in range(0,len(dirList)): # generate an index an loop over it
    print "%d)" % (i+1), dirList[i] # print a selection number matching each file

selected = raw_input("Select a file above: ")
selected = int(selected) # cast the input to int

print "You have selected:", dirList[selected-1] # you can get the corresponding entry!
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: @Boldewyn has done well to use `enumerate` so as to generate the index in the same time the list is iterated over.

Answer (score 2):

You should use enumerate for the list and then handle input errors.  Ideally this would be a function and instead of doing a `break` you would just return the selected file.

```
import os

path="/root/Desktop"
dirList=os.listdir(path)

for i, fname in enumerate(dirList):
    print "%d) %s" % (i + 1, fname)

while True:
    try:
        selectedInt = int(raw_input("Select a file above: "))
        selected = dirList[selectedInt - 1]
        break
    except Exception:
        print "Error: Please enter a number between 1 and %d" % len(dirList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, fname in enumerate(dirList):
    print "%s) %s" % (i + 1, fname)

selectedInt = int(raw_input("Select a file above: "))
selected = dirList[selectedInt - 1]
```

However, note that there is no error correction done. You should catch cases, where the input is no integer.

Answer (score 0):

You know the filename at a specific index so you can just do something like this:

```
import os
path="/root/Desktop"
dirList=os.listdir(path)

for index in range(0,len(dirList)):
    print str(index+1) + ": " + dirList[index]

selected = raw_input("Select a file above: ")
print "You selected filename: " + dirList[selected];
```

edit: oops to slow

Comment: Fixed a part and it works flawless. Thank you. --- print "You selected filename: " + dirList[int(selected)-1] ---

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

listed_files = []
for i, fname in enumerate(os.listdir("/root/Desktop")):
    print i, ': ', fname
    listed_files.append(fname)

selected = raw_input("Select a file above: ")
open("/root/Desktop/%s" % listed_files[int(selected)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary where the key is an index and the value is the filename (use enumerate(dirList) to get a tuple of (index, filename) per iteration). Then just pull the corresponding value based on the input (key).